# local python simple http erver sends wrong mime type in windows but not in linux for.svg

Tags: python, windows, firefox, svg

i have a created a simple http server in python (i haven't touched the do_GET function)

in linux (ubuntu) everything works fine
but in windows when i want to open the .svg file in firefox (so http://localhost:8000/editor.svg ) it asks me if i want to download it or save it.

it has been determined in a previous question on this site that it is because the server sends the wrong mime type

in windows the response header has content type:
'application/octet-stream'

in linux the response header has content type:
'image/svg+xml'

the local server used is exactly the same in both cases.

Does anyone know what i should do to fix this (in other words have the svg send with the correct mime type) ?
i've tried using the meta tag in the svg file to specify the content that doesn't help.

tnx

EDIT:

Silly me i really need to lean how to read the documentation better.
the the class (simpleHTTPServer.simpleRequestHandler) has an extension_map attribute that is a dictionary that maps extensions to MIME type this is exactly what i need

MODS feel free to delete this question if you want

also thank you to mikko for the answer it brought me to the right path

Comment: Since you have found the answer, better to post it.

Answer (score 4):

You want mimetypes.add_type().

http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html

Linux provides system-wide mimetypes configuration with up-to-date entries. Apparently Windows does not.